# Blender's Nearest Equivalent to Cinema 4D's Collision Deformer?

Tags: modeling, animation

What's Blender's best, simplest, and most direct equivalent to Cinema 4D's (now 3+ years old) Collision Deformer?

I'm looking for a simple and fast way to have objects deforming other objects like they were outside or the inside of them like Cinema 4D's Collision Deformer can do except I'd like to use Blender or an add-on for it instead. I've looked into Blender's soft-body physics, but I'm hoping there's a more direct equivalent to Cinema 4D's Collision Deformer than that.

Comment: Blender doesn't have exactly this. You can use a Softbody or Cloth modifier to achieve the same and set a Collision under physics for other objects. It has to be simulated and baked though, doesn't work interactively like Cinema4D's does.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I guess maybe I should request it as a feature then. It seems like the kind of thing that could make life a lot easier in the right situations. I just wish I knew the best way to request it.

Comment: You might be looking for dynamic painting with displacements.

Comment: Care to elaborate, @someonewithpc? :)